# How can I store a UIImage in an NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimage, nsdictionary

How can I store a UIImage in an NSDictionary?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
UIImage *img = ...;
[dict setObject:img forKey:@"aKeyForYourImage"];

UIImage *imgAgain = [dict objectForKey:@"aKeyForYourImage"];
```

Comment: somehow it's not working for me :( is there any additional step that's need to be done?

Comment: @raistlin This answer is *unbelievably* late at this point, but I just wanted to mention that checking if your image is empty or not (checking if it's added to target, etc.) was what fixed my issue.

Answer (score 6):

OK I had this problem recently and the above solutions never worked for me. So if someone else finds their way here to solve the same problem, here is how it's done

```
NSDictionary *imageDictionary = @{
 kImageKey:  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(/*INSERT YOUR UIImage HERE*/,0.1)
                                 };
```

// the 0.1 represents the compression quality 0.0 being lowest to 1.0 being the highest quality

then to get image back from dictionary use

```
[UIImage imageWithData:[imageDictionary objectForKey: kImageKey]];
```

Comment: There is no need for this. `NSDictionary` can store `UIImage` values as long as you don't try to persist the dictionary to a plist file.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot store UIImage object in a dictionary. You will have to convert the image into an NSData object and store that in dictionary.

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 0.0f);
[dictionary setObject:imgData forKey:@"your key"];
```

Comment: Incorrect. `NSDictionary` can store `UIImage` values as long as you don't try to persist the dictionary to a plist file.

Answer (score 1):

`[dictionary setObject:yourImage forKey:@"whatever key you want"];`

Untested ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[dict setObject:image forKey:@"ImageToStore"];

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with your NSDictionary. While, yes, you can store a UIImage in NSDictionary, you may not be able to use said dictionary object in instances where you need it to conform to certain standards.

For example, you can use an NSDictionary as a value in standardUserDefaults, but only if every object in that dictionary is a property list object. UIImage is not a property list object. NSData is, so you can convert your UIImage to NSData with UIImageJPEGREpresentation, and store it that way, as mentioned above.