# Storing UIImage in Nano Store In Motion

Tags: rubymotion

I have been reading about Nano Store in Motion and it seems I can't store an image in it's database. I have read abound storing images in NSDictionary and then storing that in Nano. Would this work, and if so how do you go about storing an image in a NSDictionary function.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of benefit:

[How can I store a UIImage in an NSDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186199/how-can-i-store-a-uiimage-in-an-nsdictionary)

RubyMotion-ized:

```
dict = NSMutableDictionary.dictionaryWithCapacity(1)
img = UIImage.imageNamed("whatever")
dict["some_key"] = img
extracted_image = dict["some_key"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a "serializable" value:

> *from https://github.com/tciuro/NanoStore*
>
> The dictionary must be serializable, which means that only the following data types are allowed:
>
> - NSArray
> - NSDictionary
> - NSString
> - NSData (*)
> - NSDate
> - NSNumber

So in your case, you could create a PNG data representation:

```
data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

You can store this data in a Hash if you want, but you'll need to convert it back to a UIImage  before using it.

```
image = UIImage.imageWithData(self, scale:UIScreen.mainScreen.scale)
```