# Array Objects update without assign

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller, nsmutabledictionary, nsobject

I want to add image from Gallery/Camera to `NSMutableDictionary` & i am using following methods which i found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186199/how-can-i-store-a-uiimage-in-an-nsdictionary)

```
[dict setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage,0.5) forKey:@"image_four"];

[documents replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:dict];

[tableOne reloadData];
```

In Cell for row at Indexpath

```
[cell.oneImgView setImage:[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[dict objectForKey:@"image_four"]]];
```

I m adding NSMutableDictionary objects into one global array in ViewController A & Sending it to ViewController B where i add/update image from gallery/camera.

but when i press back button and go back `UIViewController` A and then again go to view controller B those images are still in that array.

In short, whenever i add image to Array of `UIViewController` B it some how affects to Array of `UIViewController` A.

I want this to be done on Done button click but if i click on back button of navigation bar it does the same as Done button.

```
- (IBAction)goToBack:(id)sender {

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Can someone tell me where i m going wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do now?

Comment: what is this line "but when i press back button and go back UIViewController A and then again go to view controller B those images are still in that array"?

Comment: My problem is when i add image data to dictionary & update it to array of view controller b then it is changing in main array of previous view controller  A for no reason & no code to do such thing.

Comment: @user3182143 it means repeat step that i did earlier.

Comment: Use separate array because you are using global array.Whatever you change global array from any view controller,it affects.

Comment: ViewController A has separate array defined in interface as private & ViewController B has one array as public (so i can send objects from view controller A to B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved by copying objects of NSObject class & adding it array.

[[controllerb setDocuments1]addObjectsFromArray:array];

Comment: This is what I gave you finally in discussion part.I gave you NSObject Class.

Comment: No, As we can see in the answer, You saved it to nsuserdefaults, which is not good for memory & my approach is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

Create another array and assign the ViewController array to this array

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{ 
   ViewControllerB *controllerb = [segue destinationViewController];
   [controllerb setDocuments1:sender];
}
```

ViewControllerB.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *documents1;
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"
#import "UploadCell.h"

@interface ViewControllerB ()
{
   NSArray *arrSavedObjects;
}

@end

@implementation ViewControllerB
@synthesize documents,documents1;


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   arrSavedObjects = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"arrayObjects"];
   documents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrSavedObjects];
   if(documents.count==0)
   {
      documents = documents1;
   }
}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
   UIImage  *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  //NSMutableDictionary *dict = [documents objectAtIndex:selected];
  NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[documents objectAtIndex:selected]];
  if (![dict objectForKey:@"image1"]) {
    [dict setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.5) forKey:@"image1"];
  }
  else{
    [dict setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.5) forKey:@"image2"];
  }
  [documents removeAllObjects];
  [documents addObject:dict];

   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [defaults setObject:documents forKey:@"arrayObjects"];
   [defaults synchronize];

   [tableDocuments reloadData];
   [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Comment: It does not solve the problem, storing this many NSData is not good practice, it will slow the app comparatively.

Comment: You are asking saving objects into array and after change we go back to view controller A.Then when we come back to view controller B it should show the saved data objects.For a single set of data I saved into NSUserDefault simply.According to your question I set the solution.You must ask your question clearly.

Comment: Save only when i click on Done(completed) button not on popviewcontorller(cancel)

Comment: You have not mentioned clearly anything about the saving data whhen click the button

Comment: See my answer in discussion in chat.I updated answer using.I deleted NSUserDefault and I used the Global Array for getting.My last updated answer posted in Discussion in chart part before 14 hours.

Comment: This is the line i added first in the question, did you read the question? 

I want this to be done on Done button click but if i click on back button of navigation bar it does the same as Done button.